# text to columns in CSV

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am having data in CSV file as follows in single column:

Input:

```
Company;C Desc;Region;R Desc;
H;Hindustan;13;Maharashtra;
I;Unilever;28;Dadra;
```

I would like to change the data Text to Columns with Delimited ';' as follows:

Output:

```
Company   C Desc    Region    R Desc
H         Hindustan 13        Maharashtra
I         Unilever  28        Dadra
```

How to write this scenario in shell script?

[image: input file][image: Output file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `column` utility (most free Unices has):

```
$ column -t -s ';' infile.csv >outfile.txt

$ cat outfile.txt
Column A
Company code  Company Desc  Region Code  Region Desc
H             Hindustan     13           Maharashtra
I             Unilever      28           Dadra
```

Then it's a matter of inserting the "Column B", "Column C" etc., but it was not clear from the question if these were part of the input/output or not.

**EDIT**: After the question was clarified:

Replace the `;` in the CSV file by commas using `tr`, then re-import the file into Excel.

```
$ tr ';' ',' <infile.csv >outfile.csv
```

Excel should also be able to import your original data if you specify `;` as column delimiters.  I'm no Excel user though so I can't help with that.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I need to split the data in output file as shown in the images. Like text to columns feature in excel

Comment: @ramachandrareddyAha! I will update my answer... (after thinking).

Comment: Dear Kusalananda, Your command is working fine after modifying my CSV header. Thank you so much for your efforts. Very much appreciated your inputs

Comment: @ramachandrareddy I'm happy you got it sorted. You may consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the tick under the up-vote/down-vote buttons here to the left. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Kusalananda, thank you for your inputs. I am having numeric data also. Once it is saving into CSV all the formats are changing. Like amount (numbers) coming as "1777686.23-" instead of "-1777686.23" Please let me know how to get this minus sign as a prefix instead of suffix

Comment: @ramachandrareddy That's probably because Excel is being too clever and *probably* interprets the commas as decimal commas (or something). Try importing (not just "open") your original file and specify `;` as delimiter.

Comment: Can we do this above through shell scripting?

Comment: @ramachandrareddy I think that this is now an Excel question rather than a scripting question (my answer would be "use `tr` and replace the delimiters with something Excel understands and can use as delimiters (as in my first answer)").